# Naming NSUserDefaults with text from a plist

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I want to save a value to a NSUserDefaults but I want the name of where it's stored to be based on a string value taken from a plist file.

For example, the plist dictionary might have the strings apple, banana, orange and I want to save the NSUserDefaults as the following: storedapple, storedbanana, storedorange.

Is there a way I can create the necessary code to effectively end up with the following code (where 'storedapple', 'storedbanana' and 'storedorange' are created programatically using 'stored' and string value from plist):

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[standardUserDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"storedapple"];
[standardUserDefaults synchronize];
```

How would I extract the string from the plist too, assuming it's stored as a string value in a plist set up as follows:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>fruit</key>
        <string>apple</string>
        <key>key1</key>
        <string>data1</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>fruit</key>
        <string>banana</string>
        <key>key2</key>
        <string>data2</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

**EDIT - The code I'm now using is:**

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in tableData) {
            NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"stored%@", dict[@"fruit"]];
            [standardUserDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] forKey: key];
            [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
```

Comment: [NSString stringWithFormat:];???

Comment: do little bit of research init man.

Comment: Is the plist in an `NSArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (NSDictionary* dict in yourArray) {
    NSString *price = dict[@"price"];
    NSString *key   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"stored%@", dict[@"fruit"]];
    [standardUserDefaults setObject: price forKey: key];
}
```

NSUserDefaults is a container similar to a NSDictionary but with slightly different rules and it persists over time including app launches. It can contain items that have a name (key) and a object (value). Any value can be accessed, added or changed individually. It is really meant to save user options for an app but can be used for other things as well.

Example setting, accessing and modifying a `NSUserDefaults` item:

`NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`

To add an individual item:
`[defaults setObject: @3 forKey:@"applePrice"];`

To access an individual item:
`int price = [[defaults valueForKey:@"applePrice"] intValue];`

To modify an individual item:
`[defaults setObject: @4 forKey:@"applePrice"];`

Comment: With a bit of tweaking to fit my code, this is the answer. :)

Comment: Only problem is this creates all the NsUserDefaults whereas I only want to create specific ones at a time. How can the code be adjusted to do that?

Comment: There is one NSUserDefaults that can be used for different things, just use a different key for each unique usage.

Comment: Sorry, probably not explaining myself properly. At the moment the code loops and creates all the NSUserDefaults (i.e. storedapple, storedbanana, storedorange) and gives them all a value of 5 (see my added code in the first post edit). What I want to be able to do is target just one of the NSUserDefaults at a time (i.e. just storedbanana and give that a specific value). Does that make any more sense?

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` is a container similar to a `NSDictionary` but with slightly different rules and it persists over time including app launches. It can contain items that have a name (key) and a object (value). Any value can be accessed, added or changed individually. It is really meant to save user options for an app but can be used for other things as well. I have added some example code to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create the key using

```
for (NSDictionary * yourDictionary in yourArray)
    [standardUserDefaults setObject:yourDictionary[@"price"] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"stored%@",yourDictionary[@"fruit"]];
}
```

Comment: `[yourDictionary objectForKey:key]` more simply: `yourDictionary[key]`

Comment: Flexicoder: That seems to be very close but I'm getting an error: No visible @interace for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'objectForKey:'

Comment: @MarkStoneham when you raised the initial question you hadn't mentioned it was in an array

Comment: Sorry, I've posted the sample plist. Does the code need to change?